# Check user input string to avoid "lazy typing"

Tags: python, string, matlab, validation, user-input

I have a GUI interface in Matlab (or also Python) that asks the user for a comment to a certain event. That comment is important and is loaded in a database for future traceability of the event. That comment have to be detailed.

I would like to avoid lazy user inputs such as:

- "            "
- "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
- "safsafafa"
- "test"
- "x"
- "........."
- "qwerty"
- etc

and ask for a re-input if the "lazy input" is detected like this:

```
valid_input = 0;
while valid_input~=1
    valid_input = 0;
    user_input = '';
    user_input=InputTextRequest('Insert significant mandatory comment');
    switch user_input
        case {'exit','quit'}
            out = Popup('PROCEDURE ABORTED','PROCEDURE HAS BEEN ABORTED BY USER');
            return
        otherwise
            if CheckCommentValidity( user_input)~=1
                msg={'Comment field have to be significant:', [user_input ' is not valid, add details.']};
                out = Popup('NOTE NOT ACCEPTED',msg);
                valid_input = 0;
            else
                valid_input = 1;
            end
    end
end
```

The problem is to detect if the `user_input` is valid or not.

I came out with a function that uses for the validation 4 different parameters in the input string:

- the number of unique chars `n_unique`
- the total number of chars `n_tot`
- the number of spaces `n_space`
- the number of vowels `n_vowels`

I was wondering what checks I can do between this parameters to determine the string validity? I'm Italian so I know that my language uses for example more vowels than english but anyway, does exist a list of parameters/thresholds that describes a "correct" input?

Now I'm using this function with parameters thresholds determined at a rough guess.

```
function valid = CheckCommentValidity( user_input)
    valid=0;

    %parameters
    n_unique = length(unique(strrep(user_input,' ',''))); %number of unique chars excluded spaces
    n_tot = length(user_input); %number of chars
    n_space = sum(user_input==' '); %number of spaces
    n_space = sum(ismember( user_input, 'aeiou'));

    %sub checks
    conformity_check(1) = n_unique > 8;
    conformity_check(2) = n_tot >= 10;
    conformity_check(3) = n_space >= 1;
    conformity_check(4) = n_vowels >= 4;

    %main check
    if sum(conformity_check==1) == length(conformity_check)
        valid=1;
    else
        valid=0;
    end

end
```

**EDIT**

Some clarifications:

- This user-request-for-a-comment phase follows the one where the user can choose among several predetermined types of events but only if the `UNKNOWN` value is selected,
- Basically the user must complete this phase only if he can't find the event type in a predetermined list,
- I would like to avoid spellcheck/dictionary API approaches since there's bo builtin support in Matlab/Python,
- A machine learning approach can be useful but only for a "offline" calibration of the parameters thresholds,
- I don't think that a language Shannon entropy approach can solve the problem since the char sample is very little and I don't need to discriminate between languages,
- Maybe the `n_vowels/n_tot` ratio can be a solution,
- Of course this check cannot avoid comments with a "standard" structure but meaningless such as `This comment is useless, sorry`.

Comment: Shannon entropy comes to mind as something to at least look into; the expected entropy varies between languages.

Comment: Interesting question, you could use an external spell checking api, matlab don't provide a built-in tool for that. You could also check the time used to fill the text field.

Comment: A dictionary check would go a long way (`aeiou khzftl` is currently allowed), although it would still let things like `This is a lazy test on` pass.

Comment: This is a difficult problem because sometimes humans might not be able to tell the difference. So I guess you'd have to use some machine-learning algorithm to recognize valid and invalid comments based on manual tagging done in advance. I'd like to propose another approach altogether - how about **you** provide the user with a list of predefined comments, and let them pick a number out of a list? This would be much easier to validate, and would likely be easy enough for the user to encourage useful answers (i.e. people won't mind typing just 1 digit). This might also save you effort later on.

Comment: @Dev-iL the machine-learning solution is perhaps a little bit overkill in this case, I upvoted your comment for the "predefined comments" solution.

Comment: Checking the input time is an interesting solution @obchardon

Comment: @Dev-iL Amchine learning can be useful but only for an offline calibration of the parameters thesaurus. This "add a comment" request section follows only if the user in the previous phase select UNKNOWN among a predetermined list on events

Comment: @tripleee I think that the char sample is too little for an entropy check and I'm not interested in finding the language